# Unicode string turns garbage at serverside

Tags: asp.net, unicode, globalization

I have a situation.

I have a label in ASP.NET 2.0(C#). The label should display a dutch language text that is "Sähköpostiosoite", I tried setting the Label.Text both from markup and code-behind but what I see in the browser response is "SÃ¤hkÃ¶postiosoite".

**Originally assigned string "Sähköpostiosoite" get replaced with "SÃ¤hkÃ¶postiosoite". I have no idea why this happens** can you please help me diagnose the problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.

The asp.net page is generated by our inhouse code-generator. We did not supply the encoding format while saving the file to disk. We rectified this by telling the code-gen to use UTF8 encoding while saving the file and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and/or add HTML markup:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

Comment: This happens at the server-side.

Comment: And you are absolutely positively sure that changing the browser encoding does not solve this? At a glance, it looks like the generated bytes is correct UTF-8 and that it is your browser that has problems showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the encoding of the HTML?  In IE you can quickly switch between encodings by right-clicking and changing the active encoding from the Encoding sub-menu (there's probably a way to do it in FF too but I don't know it).  If changing the encoding (e.g. to UTF-8) fixes the text then you should specify the encoding via a HTTP header (which can set site-wde using the `<globalization />` element in web.config or via HTTP `<meta />` element in the page HTML.

See this for info on the `<globalization />` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx.